# Construct a outer derivation for every nonzero nilpotent/solvable Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

A derivation is inner if it has the form $\text{ad}x$, $x\in L$. Otherwise, a derivation is outer. For a semisimple Lie algebra, every derivation is inner. What about the nilpotent and solvable cases?

Answer (score 2):

*Every* nonzero nilpotent Lie algebra over an arbitrary field has an outer derivation. This was proved by Dixmier, and by Jacobson and Schenkmann in $1955$.

This is no longer true for solvable Lie algebras. Already the nonabelian $2$-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{r}_2(K)$ has only inner derivations.

Reference: [Why, for nilpotent Lie Algebras, is the inclusion to the derivations $x \mapsto {ad}_x$ not surjective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605402/why-for-nilpotent-lie-algebras-is-the-inclusion-to-the-derivations-x-mapsto)

Yves has written down there the proof for nilpotent Lie algebras.

Note: It is *not* true, that all derivations of semisimple Lie algebras are inner. Consider the simple Lie algebra $L=\mathfrak{psl}_3(\Bbb F_3)$. Then we even have $\operatorname{Out}(L)\cong L$, see [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_67_modular.pdf).

Comment: Your answer really broadens my mind. I think that the semisimple Lie algebra over an field of characteristic 0 has $\text{ad}L=\text{Der}L$

Comment: Yes, this is true. We need characteristic zero.